# Is lxqt-sudo the only valid alternative for gksudo?

Tags: sudo, gui, alternative, lxqt, gksudo

since ubuntu 4.10 i always used gksudo regularly, and then, few years ago, gksudo simply disappeared from the repository, forcing me to look for old and unsupported .deb packages and install from there instead.

then i found lxqt-sudo, which i'm trying now and see if it works fine as gksudo replacement.

(i'm asking this because pkexec is indeed totally useless and confusing (i was seeing i'm not alone saying this), and i used gksudo all the time in almost everything - so i'm still looking for gksudo and lxqt-sudo alternatives, and also asking for developers creating such alternatives if they still don't exist)

Comment: there are supposed to be built-in replacements, what are you trying to do with gksudo?

Comment: No it's not; `lxqt-sudo` is LXQt specific & would be inefficient to be used by systems not also running the LXQt & Qt5 desktop. If you scan the ML when `gksudo` was *deprecated* examples using `pkexec` were provided as just a single alternative but there are many (including many desktop specific like `lxqt-sudo` that will be efficient when using the specific desktop)

Comment: Please edit your question and add details on which flavour of Ubuntu your are using, as there are options - depending on the desktop environment.
Except this: which GUI applications you intend to run which root privileges? It's normally not necessary and may mess up your system pretty badly.